# Sequlize.max внутри include

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Возможно ли получить максимальный `id` внутри `include`?

Чтобы вместо этого:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name_1",
        "avatar": "avatar_1",
        "chats": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "text": "Привет",
                        "createdAt": "2021-12-29T08:32:48.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-12-29T08:32:48.000Z",
                        "userId": 1,
                        "chatId": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "text": "Приветик",
                        "createdAt": "2021-12-29T08:32:55.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-12-29T08:32:55.000Z",
                        "userId": 2,
                        "chatId": 1
                    },
                    ...
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "text": "Пока",
                        "createdAt": "2021-12-29T08:33:49.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-12-29T08:33:49.000Z",
                        "userId": 1,
                        "chatId": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "text": "Пока",
                        "createdAt": "2021-12-29T08:33:53.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-12-29T08:33:53.000Z",
                        "userId": 2,
                        "chatId": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Получить только один `messages` с максимальным `id`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name_1",
        "avatar": "avatar_1",
        "chats": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "text": "Пока",
                        "createdAt": "2021-12-29T08:33:53.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-12-29T08:33:53.000Z",
                        "userId": 2,
                        "chatId": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Пробовал так:

```
const chatGroup = await ChatGroup.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'avatar'],
    include: [{
        model: Chat,
        where: { userId },
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: Message,
            attributes: [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('id'))]
        }]
    }]

    return res.json(chatGroup);
});
```

Но получаю ошибку: `Tried to select attributes using Sequelize.cast or Sequelize.fn without specifying an alias for the result, during eager loading. This means the attribute will not be added to the returned instance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
const chatGroup = await ChatGroup.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'avatar'],
    include: [{
        model: Chat,
        where: { userId },
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: Message,
            attributes: ['id', 'text', 'createdAt'],
            limit: 1,
            order: [['id', 'DESC']]
        }]
    }]

    return res.json(chatGroup);
});
```